Discussions is a dumpster fire, please help
The idea behind Discussions is a breath of fresh air. I've wanted a more open-ended exchange with people on Stack Overflow and all across the network.
Unfortunately, this experiment is being spoiled by rampant spam. It's actually hard to declare this a success or failure from a community perspective because of the noise and frustration that spam is causing.
I realize we have other questions addressing this, but seriously, the entire first page is spam:

Please fix this.
I really would like to see this succeed, and I don't mind picking up the garden hose to put out some small fires, but flagging this much spam this frequently is a full-time job that I'm not getting paid for. And I've got bills to pay.
A good answer should include exactly what is being done and the release date for whichever mitigation strategies are being decided on.
I won't be back to Discussions until spam has been dramatically reduced. Then the experiment can continue.

More calls for help:

Who is upvoting spam in discussions (and can they please stop)?
Can we ask for more discussion moderators to speed up the cleaning in discussions?
What more can be done to get rid of illegal content in Discussions?
What can be done to combat the spam in discussions?


If Discussions involved AI somehow it would be taken more seriously. Maybe they should add chatbots to discussions.

[so] refuse to learn their lesson; until they do, it's better off dead.

On second thought, what if we just roll with it? Rebrand "Discussions" as "Free online classifieds". Now all the content fits. No additional work is necessary. We might actually have a competitor for Craigs List. Thoughts?

Honestly, do, @GregBurghardt . I suspect that inaction is the only thing that is going to force [so] to take action. The irony is not lost on me.

It is a fight, on a live stream. SE vs SPAM. And we all get to watch it. What a great way to spend my weekend.

Though it looks like this has already been cleaned up, this is a good example of why API access is the most urgent priority. Days since I told a CM this: 0. Let's see what SE comes back with to handle this.

Isn't this duplicate of the other questions you linked to though? Specifically the last two. I just pinged a CM last night, and as Laurel mentioned, we have had a discussion with them just today, so need to give it some time. In the meantime, I should remind you that we have had chat for more open-ended exchanges since forever. But SO chose to reinvent the wheel.

Was Discussions ever well-moderated? I don't think so. The company has had many cuts in the last few years and perhaps Discussions was rolled out at exactly the wrong time. With limited resources, it appears the company has (correctly, IMHO) de-prioritized Discussions and that's unlikely to change.  Your choices may be 1) the crap that is Discussions now, or 2) nothing at all, Discussions is killed. Caveat: I don't really know how much effort/resources it takes to deal with spam.

I operate in the "America not Online" hours mostly and in that time period it's not THAT bad, but I do tend to see a dozen of them yes. I am more confused by the fact that I don't see a button to reply to a reply. According to the documentation... that should be possible. I have not seen a reply to a reply in the wild yet though. So now people are responding to me and I don't really have a way to acknowledge them :/ The discussions feature is practically useless to me like this because it is effectively an echo chamber, regardless of spam.

From the outside (of SO) and as a 'insider' of the broader SE community - I feel like there's certain historical parallels here with the old NPR.

Stack Overflow would remain as laser sharp focused as possible, and NPR would host all those exciting and sometimes helpful (but not really answerable) questions.
However, as it usually happens, theory and practice are two entirely different beasts. NPR's promise proved extremely attractive to people who were more interested in posting joke answers, or just repeating earlier answers, or posting outright crap (Do you fart in the cubicle?). It didn't take long for everyone to realize that the site was not working, and most people just didn't bother with it.

As a mental exercise - just swap out 'NPR' for discussions, and consider how much of this is still true. I'm a (partial) believer in the broken window theory for the internet - that a clean, useful and welcoming site with quality content will attract quality content. A site filled with spam, and low quality content will attract garbage. We don't really want SO chan but I'd wonder what the vision for a successful discussions/board platform on SO looks like.
There's the additional quirk of this being essentially a new format... almost. The closest thing I can think of are oldschool image boards at this point. There's a certain lack of structure. Most of the guidance I can find is about mechanics, but building healthy culture is important too.
Automated/API access for smokey to clean up aside, its probably worth it for the people who designed this/are the owners of the project to take a good look at where things are wrong broadly,  and why folks are not curating.
And a critical question here is what does this do that existing tools don't, and if there's an overlap, why would someone use discussions over other formats, and both a consideration of if its a right fit for  the SE model, something that can stand on its own merits, or something that could be, on its own or in part a useful product.
I've certain biases here of course - that we've already have a neglected third space, but fundamentally - as something the company has built on its own initiative, in an attempt to try to branch off from the Q&A space yet again, It is up to the company to give it the best chance of survival. That could mean spending resources and staff to guide and curate the discussions platform to the point where the community feels its worth the effort and time to do it itself.

Spam aside, I don't see a problem with discussions, though. It's like we've been given a picnic table where we can all hang out and talk about deeper topics, but SO didn't bother putting it under a pavilion, so every seagull flying by poops on the table. The answer should be "put the table under a pavilion" not "walk away from the table" but that's our only choice at the moment. I'm really hoping for a pavilion, while also fully understanding that it is a non-trivial amount of work.

Well - more that its been tried before (and failed), and least to me, discussions in its current format distracts from chat. Also, it is a non trivial amount of work, anything worth doing is.

"... its probably worth it for the people who designed this... to take a good look at where things are wrong broadly, and why folks are not curating." — It's because of all the spam. I can't see past the spam. They need to do something about all the spam. If they do, I bet people will curate more. I would love to be an active participant and curator, but I just can't deal with the spam. They need to fix the spam.

It's not just the spam though, @GregBurghardt . There a lot of just code dump "discussions" and incredibly vague, honestly bad discussion questions like "What are your opinions of coding? Explain your reasons.", and question that would be off-topic for the main site but too low quality for it. There needs to be better everything.

@ThomA, but that's exactly the kind of thing SE is missing. A place for people to have these conversations without it disappearing into the abyss of chat history.

Code dumps arent any good for Discussions either though, @GregBurghardt . There is some content that is good there, but my point is that the amount is few and far between.

"I'm a (partial) believer in the broken window theory for the internet - that a clean, useful and welcoming site with quality content will attract quality content." - Exactly. Which is why I'm doing my part for Codidact.

@GregBurghardt Even when there's no spam up, then 80% of it is NSFD

Please don't help. The only help that is useful is for the company to fix discussions. To make discussion posts detectable by smokey. To allow viewing of deleted discussions. To allow downvotes.
Until that point, don't help. Instead, let's go on strike. Stop moderating discussions. Stop flagging. Stop handling flags. LET IT BURN!
If SE won't make the minimal effort to make discussions moderateable, why should we continue to moderate it?

I'm not even flagging things as spam anymore. I agree. The mods cannot fix this. Unfortunately this is a hard lesson that the minimal features necessary even to experiment with user generated content is some form of automated spam mitigation.
